# what's wrong with my prometheus configuration?

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to running prometheus on kubernetes cluster, my prometheus configuration is injected into prometheus by configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-config
  namespace: monitoring
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval: 10s
      scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'kubelet'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node
        scheme: https
        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
```

however, the prometheus pod can't startup, the error log is below:

```
level=error ts=2020-07-04T02:27:32.831Z caller=main.go:758 err="error loading config from \"/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\": couldn't load configuration (--config.file=\"/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\"): parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 3: field scrape_configs not found in type config.plain"
```

I have carefully read the prometheus documentation, but don't find a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scrape_configs` should be on the same level as `global`.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-config
  namespace: monitoring
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval: 10s
    scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'kubelet'
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: node
      scheme: https
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
```

[Valid config example](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/release-2.19/config/testdata/conf.good.yml)